# ScrollView UIRefreshControl is not calling function

Tags: swift, ios10, uirefreshcontrol

I added a refreshControl to a scrollView in iOS 10 an swift 3, but the added function is not called.

Here is my code.

```
let rc = UIRefreshControl()
rc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    scrollView.refreshControl = rc
}

...

@objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let response = serverHelper.send(word: JSONParser.getAllGamesForPlayer(player: localPlayer))
    let games = JSONParser.parseToArrayDic(string: response)
    print("All games \(games)")
    addAllGameButtons(games: games)
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

I want that the `refreshContol` is calling the `refresh` function.
But the function is never called.
What I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT

The refreshControl is working, but the problem is, that I have to scroll down to the end of the screen so that the function gets called.
My scrollView has a high of 1200 px.
Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, learn how to format your text properly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Use ` for inline code and 4 spaces for multiple lines.

Comment: I copied your code and it's working. Did you run on iOS 10 or older?

Comment: I'm running on simulator iOS 10.2
I've setted a breakpoint in the func and it's never stoped

Answer (score 9):

I had this bug when my view controller had `size: freeform` of 1500px on the storyboard.
When I changed it to fixed size & inferred, the refresh started to work as expected.

Looks like a bug on Apple's side that the refresh control, value change distance is set when the view is loaded from Xib/Storyboard but not updated when it is laid out for the device.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, your answer save me, Otherwise I will try some third party libraries for scroll view. Thank You

Comment: that's right when I set freeform to fixed my problem solved